# Compare old and new value in DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

How to change DataGridView cell ForeColor based on whether new cell value is > or < than current/old cell value?  Is there an event which passes the new value before the current is changed, so I can compare them?

The data is updated from underlying source, and may be bound by BindingSource.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue. I tackled this by using the `CellValidating` event instead:

```
void dgv_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    var oldValue = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
    var newValue = e.FormattedValue;
}
```

Admittedly, I just needed access to the old value, I didn't need to perform any formatting.  I'm sure you can apply formatting through this event handler, though.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner source of DataGridView control is a DataTable then you can utilize the older version of DataRow using DataRowVersion enum. Note that I have utilized CellFormatting Event.

Example:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // if NOT the DataGridView's new row
    if (!this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
    {
        // if my desired column
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            TestDataSet.TestRow row;

            row = (TestDataSet.TestRow)((DataRowView)this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row;

            if (row.Column1, (int)row["Column1", DataRowVersion.Original]) > 0)
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the `DataGridView.CellValueChanged`event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx).

If you want to check the value before it is saved, then look at `DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
var cell = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    if (cell.Value != e.FormattedValue)
    {
       // Current cell value: cell.Value
       // New cell value: e.FormattedValue
       // ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

You can store the old value of the cell in a variable, to compare and change the ForeColor depending on the result, then delete the old value from the variable.

Regards.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, as I need for many columns, but if it's no easier way...

Answer (score -1):

```
    private double CuerrLineQty;
    private void GridTransaction_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currOp != CurrentOperation.FillDone)
            return;

        CuerrLineQty = double.Parse(GridTransaction.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DisplayQty"].Value.ToString());
        
        CuerrLineQty = double.Parse(GridTransaction.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DisplayQty"].FormattedValue.ToString());

        CuerrLineQty = double.Parse(GridTransaction.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DisplayQty"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString());

    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41mHq.png)