# In a DataGridView, how do you get the pre-edited cell values back in that row?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I created a DataRow and set it equal to the row of the DataSet that is the equivalent current row of the grid. I want to isolate the original pre-edited values so I can revert back to these values in the grid if the user cancels the edits for that row. But the grid seems to be bound to the DataSet so that it is not isolating the original pre-edited cell values. I coded so it only creates the DataRow once in the CellBeginEdit event. But each time I edit a cell, the DataRow is changing and reflecting the new edited values. I tried using a DataGridViewRow but it also changed automatically with each cell edit rather than being an independent snapshot of the row at the time it was created. Here is my code:

```
private void gridDB_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)

{

string test;
//DataGridViewRow currRow= new DataGridViewRow(); This kept updating with each edit   


//rowSet is public bool and currRow is public DataRow
if (rowSet != true) 
{    
    currRow = dSet.Tables[0].Rows[gridDB.CurrentRow.Index];    
    rowSet = true;
}

test = "In CellBeginEdit " + currRow[0].ToString() + "  " +
       currRow[1].ToString() + "  " +
       currRow[2].ToString() + "  " +
       currRow[3].ToString() + "  " +
       currRow[4].ToString();

MessageBox.Show(test);
}
```

Each time it came to this test string, it was showing each new edited cell edit. This told me that currRow is not a static snapshot of the DataSet row at the time it was created.

Please tell me why this does not work and advise me of the best way to be accomplish this.

Thank you!

Valhalla

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060152/compare-old-and-new-value-in-datagridview-cell

Comment: Is it as easy as just using grid.EndEdit(); and grid.CancelEdit();???

Comment: I just tried simply putting gridDB.EndEdit(); and gridDB.CancelEdit(); and it appears to be working. This seems too easy so I'm doubting if this is all it takes.

Comment: Thanks Emmad...that had the same title but was not what I was looking for...

Comment: If you want "reset" all values to origins then show how you get data to `DataGridView`. Just copy datasource to some variable and rebound it on reset command

Comment: The grid.EndEdit(); and grid.CancelEdit(); worked in the RowLeave event.... Like so many things, the answer was so simple I over looked it... :) (I had not saved the changes to the database and just wanted the grid changes to go away and go back to what was there before the edits) Thanks!