# How to know the old value in DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to make conversion of cost when to unity is changed, I have to know the old value to make that.
I have this gives me the new value:

```
dgvRow.Cells["unity"].Value.ToString();
```

is there any way to get the old value?

Comment: You should add more code, like in what event you are doing this and what is changing cell value like a user input etc.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060152/compare-old-and-new-value-in-datagridview-cell

Comment: @Anil the event is DataGridView.CellValueChanged

Comment: You could use the CellBeginEdit event to store the old value in the Tag.

Comment: thank you @TaW  the CellBeginEdit  event is the solution.