# C# Windows Form - How to get previous/old value of cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview. I'm trying to get the old value (value before edit) and the new value, then compare.

```
private void GridDetails_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == GridDetails.Columns["Address"].Index)
        {
            var oldValue = GridDetails[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
            var newValue = GridDetails[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue;

            if(oldValue!=newValue)
            {
                GridDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Address"].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(212, 212, 155);
            }

        }
    }
```

But Both old and new values are the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775912/14171304

Comment: @dr.null still the old value returns the new value.

Comment: No It doesn't if you get the new value from the `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs` arg. Keep the `oldValue` code as is and get the new value as so: `var newValue = e.FormattedValue;`. Also, what is the type of the column? Maybe you need to convert the values to the right type to compare them.

Comment: var newValue = e.FormattedValue; I agree with you. This line returns the new value. But,

var oldValue = GridDetails[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value; this code line also returns the new value. not the old value.

Comment: What is type of the column in question? CheckBox, TextBox, ...etc? Are you committing the edit somewhere in your code?

Comment: @dr.null The column type is TextBox.  No, I'm not committing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use CellBeginEdit Event of the DataGrid and store the value somewhere Then use CellEndEdit to Compare the new Value with the old value.

Comment: please upvote if worked. this will help the others.

Answer (score 1):

Chamod, you are right. I used CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit, and it worked. Below is my answer.

```
string oldValue;
private void GridDetails_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
        oldValue = GridDetails[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}


private void GridDetails_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == GridDetails.Columns["Address"].Index)
    {
       
        string newValue = e.FormattedValue.ToString();

        if(oldValue!=newValue)
        {
            GridDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Address"].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(212, 212, 155);
        }

    }
}
```